# Primal Dual Interior Point convergence.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have developed a Primal Dual Interior point algorithm to solve linear inequality constrained Quadratic problems. But sometimes  it cannot reduce the residual so as to satisfy the stop criteria. I mean the residual decreases and reaches some value (that I think depends on the scale of the matrices) and then it gets stuck at that value. How should I deal with this dilemma? I have studied an article about  Predictor Corrector method, but it is noted in the article that sometimes this method does not converge. Is there any method that leads to  definite convergence? And one more question,Is PDIPM even a good choice for solving quadratic problems? Is there any more advanced stop criteria other than primal and residual norm ,that varies with scale and size of variables ?

Comment: PDIPM with predictors/correctors is the method of choice, all major solvers rely on it. Look at the MOSEK paper for ideas; a good starting point helps. Residual of what? Primal/dual feasibility? What does stuck mean? Is your step length severely limited by the boundary?

Comment: @LinAlg by residual I meant primal and dual residual,and getting stuck means in line search the step length become so small such that $ x + \alpha dx = x$ and so the algorithm does not proceed.the step length is computed via back tracking line search and it has to be small enough not to   exceed primal and dual feasibility.So you mean predictor corrector is a good choice?

Comment: I assume that you are performing your computations in double precision.  In practice, the Newton’s method step equations become very badly conditioned as you approach an optimal solution.  Have you considered this I’ll-conditioning?

Comment: You can mitigate small steps by using a better starting point and by using predictor/corrector methods. Standard Mehrotra should be a big step forward (hehe), but Gondzio's papers are worth looking into.

Comment: @BrianBorchers yes exactly, the matrix associated with linear systems going to be solved in each iteration some times become nearly singular,What should I do about that?

Comment: @LinAlg,Thank you ,I will check them out.

Comment: How accurate a solution are you trying to get?  In practice, using double precision, with careful attention to details like scaling you might be able to get a solution accurate to about 7 to 8 digits at best using IEEE 754 double precision.

Comment: @BrianBorchers ill conditioning some times happens even for 4 digit accuracy,That I think as you mentioned  is because of using double precision and also the scale of the matrices,Thank you.